# Failing to run Robolectric test

Tags: android, gradle, classpath

I don't know what causes the issue, but I can not run unit tests:

```
Execution failed for task ':module:mockableAndroidJar'.
> org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode.<init>(I)V
```

Are there command line parameter to see the classpath? Reading few answers about similar error, looks like I have wrong asm library in my classpath

Comment: What if you create a new project from scratch and try to write a unit test for that? (Even a trivial failing test, like `int a = 2/0;`).

Comment: are you using retrolambda in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I expected the issue was in having old `asm` in classpath.

You can see classpath of you gradle in start of the log. I also used next snippet to see it:

```
task show << {
    buildscript.configurations.classpath.each { println it }
}
```

And solution to solve our problem next:

```
classpath('com.terrafolio:gradle-jenkins-plugin:1.2.3') {
    exclude group: 'asm', module: 'asm-tree'
    exclude group: 'asm', module: 'asm'
}
```

And now I have another issue - lint task is failing. Looking for solution.

Comment: Same happens on travis-ci if you have jacoco. You are life saver man! :)
Lint is failing for me too, with error processing exploded aars, even excluded all "lint" tasks and disabled all lint tasks. I passed it by setting to quite and reading the reports. :/